# Qiskit simulator intermediate results

Tags: python, qiskit

Is it possible to get an intermediate result from qiskit simulator?

Let's suppose I have a really simple circuit.

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";

qreg q[2];
creg c[2];

h q[0];
z q[0];
measure q[0] -> c[0];
```

I would like to get the vector state after applying the H gate and then again after applying the Z gate. I can not use the measurement gate, because I would lose the qubit state.

Can I query the qubit/vector for each step in a circuit?

Comment: https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-states/representing-qubit-states.html

Comment: I just answered basically the same question here. https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/20894/saving-statevector-on-more-than-one-location-in-a-quantum-circuit-in-qiskit/20967#20967

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Qiskit programing language:- 
You could use 
`save_statevector()` function to save intermediate values.
But i believe you are speaking of *OPENQASM*. 
In that case please surf through this [Github](https://qiskit.github.io/openqasm/) respo to see if you can find an answer.